# Show MessageBox if Entry empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, tkinter, attributeerror

Could someone tell me what`s wrong I did?! I am tring to create GUI with tkinter in Python 3. **If user click the button and in the same time Entry is empty I want to show messageBox.** Here below my code that I used.

Right know I have this **ERROR**:

```
if len(self.entryBox.get()) == 0:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Also I tried to use this if `self.entryBox is None:` but in that case I see messageBox immediately after run the project which is now correct. I am really comfused.

CODE:

```
    from tkinter import *

    class Application(Frame):
         def __init__(self, master):
            super(Application, self).__init__(master)
            self.grid()
            self.widgets()

         def widgets(self):
            self.entryBox = Entry(self).grid()
            Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.search()).grid()

         def search(self):
             if len(self.entryBox.get()) == 0:
                 tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Warning!", "Box is empty! Write something")
             else:
                 do_something()

    # main
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Title")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The line `self.entryBox = Entry(self).grid()` will assign the result of `.grid()` to `self.entryBox`. Intead, try this:

   ```
   self.entryBox = Entry(self)
   self.entryBox.grid()
   ```
2. By doing `Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.search()).grid()` you have a similar problem, as you run the `search` method once and then bind the result of that method to the `command` parameter. Instead, this should work (note the absence of `()`:

   ```
   Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.search).grid()
   ```

Comment: Well, it so strange. I dont have AttributeError now but I have second problem which I described in my post also. I see messageBox immediately after run the project. I need to see it only if user didnt write anything in Entry and click submit button. I hope you understand me.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek Sorry, did not see the second issue. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the button gets called as soon as the function is called, replace the line with

```
Button(self, text="Submit", command=lambda: self.search()).grid()
```

This worked fine for me

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class Application(Frame):
     def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.widgets()

     def widgets(self):
        self.entryBox = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entryBox.grid()
        print(self.entryBox.get())
        Button(self, text="Submit", command=lambda: self.search()).grid()
        print(self.entryBox)
     def search(self):
         print(self.entryBox.get())
         if len(self.entryBox.get()) == 0:
             tk.messagebox.showinfo("Warning!", "Box is empty! Write something")
         else:
             do_something()

# main
root = Tk()
root.title("Title")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I used lambda as you said but I have new errors inside __init__.py file as
    `(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-wrap"` Do you have any ideas about that?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two problems :

**(1) self.entryBox**

The code

```
self.entryBox = Entry(self).grid()
```

will make self.entryBox the **return value** of grid(), not the Entry widget object. Change that line to

```
self.entryBox = Entry(self)
self.entryBox.grid()
```

**(2) Binding the command to the button**

When you bind a callback function to the button, you have to pass the **function itself**. Change

```
Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.search()).grid()
```

to

```
Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.search).grid()
```

. Furthermore, if you set the Button as an attribute,

```
self.button = Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.search)
self.button.grid()
```

You may be able to control the button in the other methods.

The following example works in my computer.

```
# -----
# from tkinter import *
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
# -----

class Application(Frame, object):
     def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.widgets()

     def widgets(self):
        #self.entryBox = Entry(self).grid()
        self.entryBox = Entry(self)
        self.entryBox.grid()

        self.button = Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.search)
        self.button.grid()

     def search(self):
         if len(self.entryBox.get()) == 0:
             # -----
             # messagebox.showinfo("Warning!", "Box is empty! Write something")
             tkMessageBox.showinfo("Warning!", "Box is empty! Write something")
             # -----
         else:
             # do_something()
             # -----
             # print(self.entryBox.get())
             print self.entryBox.get()
             # -----

# main
root = Tk()
root.title("Title")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

(I don't have python 3 now, so I modified some lines to the python 2 style.)

Comment: Hello! I wrote as you said but I have new errors inside init.py file as `(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf)) _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-wrap"` Do you have any ideas about that? I am really comfused.

Comment: I installed python 3.5, and tried the following :

http://pastebin.com/5W7Uj8YG

( result : http://tinypic.com/r/2vifk9u/9 )

I think this code works well in my python 3. Maybe that error is due to something outside the code.

Comment: Is init.py another module you wrote? Then, how about posting the source of that module?